# Inconsistent behavior concatenating lists and tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, concatenation

I noticed a surprising behavior when trying to concatenate lists and tuples.

Usually, they don't mix:

```
(0, 1) + [2, 3]
```

results in:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

and, vice versa

```
[0, 1] + (2, 3)
```

gives:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

So far, nothing was unexpected.
However, if you use a variable assignment via "+=", the behavior for lists changes!

```
l = [0, 1]
l += (2, 3)
l
```

gives

> [0, 1, 2, 3]

But not for tuples:

```
t = (0, 1)
t += [2, 3]
t
```

still produces an error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Of course, there is no practical problem here, but I'm curious: 
What's going on there?

Comment: forgot to mention the python version: 3.6.8

Comment: Please check `tuple` and `list` basic concepts. list is immutable and tuple is immutable.

Comment: @Harsha They're both immutable…?!

Comment: Well, the *type* `list` is immutable :)

Comment: @deceze spelling mistake: list is mutable and tuple is immutable

Comment: @chepner : List is mutable.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani An *instance* of `list` is mutable; the *type* `list` itself is not. That was the basis of my joke.

Comment: @chepner : hahahaha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`+=` for lists doesn't expect an actual list as its right-hand operand; it will accept any iterable value. It is effectively an operator version of `list.extend` (which *also* accepts an arbitrary iterable value).

`tuple` doesn't define `__iadd__` at all, so `t += [2, 3]` is just syntactic sugar for `t = t + [2,3]`, and we've already confirmed that `tuple.__add__` can't add a tuple and a list together.

Answer (score 2):

Each part on its own makes sense, putting it all together as you have happens to reveal inconsistencies.

Tuples define `__add__` and accept other tuples to be concatenated together. Makes sense, you can add two things of the same type together. Same thing for lists, you can `+` two lists together.

Tuples are immutable, so they don't define an `__iadd__` (`+=`).

Lists *are* mutable and define an `extend` method, *which accepts any iterable*. So you can do things like:

```
lst.extend(map(str, range(42)))
```

Neat and convenient. `+=` is basically an alias for that.

So:

- `tuple + tuple` works
- `list + list` works
- `tuple + list` doesn't work, because they're different types
- `list + tuple` also doesn't work, as expected
- `list.extend`/`list +=` works with any iterable, including tuples
- `+=` on tuples is executed as `a = a + b` because they're immutable, so doesn't work if `a` and `b` are of different types

Comment: This makes perfect sense. My answer missed this by a mile :)

Comment: *"Tuples are immutable, so they don't define an `__iadd__`"* Well, that's a bit of a non-sequitur. Tuples *could* implement `__iadd__` so that `+=` accepts any iterable on the right-hand side. It's not like `__iadd__` has to actually modify the tuple in-place, after all.

Comment: Just to add:  `t += 2,3` "works", but a new tuple object is created (since tuples are immutable).  If you use `id(t)` after each step you can see that (assuming the C implementation).

Comment: @Aran Faaair enough, but the presence of `__iadd__` mostly makes sense for mutable types, not so much for immutable ones.

Comment: @cdarke Yes, as I wrote, `a = a + b` works, if `tuple + tuple` works…

Comment: @deceze:  I wanted to underline that the tuple object is not extended, a new one is created (like `+=` with `str`).